# Чи правильно вживати "шуми серця"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи правильно вживати словосполучення «шуми в серці»? На  [офіційному сайті української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/chislo_imennikiv/6-1-0-89) зазаначено, що лише однину мають збірні іменники (Singularia tantum). Слово "шум" в  [Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/shum)-сукупність різноманітних звуків, які швидко змінюються за частотою і силою. Отже, це слово мало б вживатися лише в однині.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Це процес зміщення значення, бо лікарі надають шумам, болям інше, менш загальне і більш конкретне значення.

> Іноді від названих іменнників може утворюватись форма множини, але при
>   цьому відбувається зміщення у лексичному значенні. Зокрема через форму
>   мнножини конкретне зачення може протиставлятися більш загальному, тоді
>   форми множини набувають спеціалізованих значень, а саме:
>
> 1. сортів або різновидів речовин і матеріалів: мед - меди, вода - води, сталь - сталі, масло - масла;
> 2. різних проявів абстрактних ознак: швидкість - швидкості;
> 3. співвідношення величин за масою, розміром або інтенсивністю вияву: пісок - піски, сніг - сніги, жито - жита, біль - болі;
> 4. однойменних осіб або предметів: Привіт вам, Петрики, Марусі, Олі, Гриці (М. Рильський);
> 5. номінанацій, узагальнених на основі характеристичних ознак, пов'язаних з відповідними власними назвами: Давайте нам літературу.
>      Давайте Байронів, Шекспірів, Гете (М. Коцюбинський);
> 6. сукупності осіб, пов'язаних родинними стосунками: родина Королів.

[Підручник з СУМ](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/imen/alf.htm)